# Универсальный запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Передаю атрибуты HTML элемента на сервер:

```
 var attributes = elem_name.attributes;
 var ret = [];
 for (var key in attributes) {
      if (attributes[key].nodeName) {
           ret.push(encodeURIComponent(attributes[key].nodeName) 
           + '=' 
           + encodeURIComponent(attributes[key].nodeValue));
      }
 }
 var text = ret.join('&');
 $.get( "index.php",text)
 .done(function( data ) {
 });
```

Количество атрибутов и сами атрибуты всегда меняются, т.к. используются разные HTML элементы. Разновидностей атрибутов всего где то 10. Думаю не рационально делать так:

```
 // Перечисление всех возможных принятых значений
 $id= $_GET['id'];
 $class= $_GET['class'];
 $data= $_GET['data'];
 $data1= $_GET['data1'];
 // и т.д.
 // Перечисление всех возможных значений в запросе
 $result = mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO blabla (id, class, data, data1 и т.д.) VALUES (" . $id. "," . $class. ", " . $data. ", " . $data1. " и т.д.)");

 Подскажите пожалуйста более рациональный вариант
```

Comment: А в чем собственно вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не собирайте SQL запрос таким образом. Прямая подстановка переменных чревата множеством проблем, начиная от банальной сложности отладки и кончая SQL-инъекциями.

Используйте [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) и [привязку значений](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)